# Overlay inner div visible

Tags: javascript, html, css, overlay

I have added an overlay `div` to be shown when the page gets refresh/reload. It works properly. But the problem is after the page successfully loaded the place where I created the `div` shows the "loading" message.

here is my code:
style:

```
#overlay {
    position: fixed;
    top: 20%;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: white;
    z-index: 999;
    visibility: hidden;
}

#overlay div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 5em;
    height: 2em;
    margin: -1em 0 0 -2.5em;
    color: #000;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: Can you include your HTML as well? This is only half of the picture.

Comment: Can we have your code in fiddle please.

Answer (score 0):

Try This One

```
#container{
       position:relative;
   z-index:0;
}
#overlay {
   visibility:hidden; 
   top: 20%;
   right: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   left: 0;
   background-color: white;
   z-index: 999;
   position: absolute; 
}
#overlay div   
{ 
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
width: 5em;
height: 2em;
margin: -1em 0 0 -2.5em;
color: #000;
font-weight: bold;
}
```